# Is the SQL Server 2012 version of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' geometry UDT backward compatible with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, spatial, backwards-compatibility, sqlgeometry

If I had both SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012 installed locally, I would simply try this for myself; however I only have the newer version installed and would like to keep it that way.

- SQL Server 2008 comes with an assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll`, major version 10.
- SQL Server 2012 comes with an assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll`, major version 11.

Among other things, both assemblies expose a [`SqlGeometryBuilder` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometrybuilder.aspx). The one notable difference between the two assembly versions is that the 2012 type has an additional overloaded method `AddCircularArc`, and the 2008 type does not.

Since [it's not exactly trivial (and perhaps a bad idea) to reference both assemblies in parallel](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008/11/visual-studio-referencing-same-assembly.html), I wonder whether I can just use the 2012 version — even against a SQL Server 2008 instance, as long as I don't make use of `AddCircularArc`.

Can anyone share their experience if they have tried this?

Comment: The section _"SQL CLR Data Types (geometry, geography, and hierarchyid)"_ of the MSDN page [_"Breaking Changes to Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2012"_](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179.aspx) doesn't go into this issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default SqlClient uses version 10.0 of the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types assembly (even if you reference a newer version in your project). When two different versions of that assembly are loaded at the same time you may see strange runtime exceptions like "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry' to type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry'."...

The following article describes some possibilities that you have to use the newer Microsoft.SqlServer.Types assemblies with SqlClient: 
[Breaking Changes to Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179.aspx)

The options are:

- Calling the GetSqlBytes method, instead of the Get methods (e.g. SqlGeometry.Deserialize(reader.GetSqlBytes(0)))
- Using assembly redirection in the application configuration
- Specifying a value of "SQL Server 2012" for the "Type System Version" attribute to force SqlClient to load version 11.0 of the assembly

I personally favor the "Type System Version" connection string keyword. See the MSDN article here:
[SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) and search for 'Type System Version'.

Comment: +1 for the "Type System Version" attribute to resolve the issue of casting between the two versions of SQL Server

Comment: Two facts ([that I have learnt in the meantime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675774/is-the-sql-server-2012-version-of-microsoft-sqlserver-types-geometry-udt-backwa#comment38074389_14855882)) that are missing from your answer are that version 11 is backward compatible with version 10, but version 10 is only partially forward compatible with version 11. I am nevertheless accepting your answer because it's really important to realise that some explicit work must be done to have version 11 loaded.

Comment: There's also a chance that you don't have version 11 installed on your computer. In that case, you'll also have to download the 2012 SQL feature pack: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065

Comment: Also see [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39589720/3085342) for alternative options if you don't have v11 (or later) installed

Answer (score 7):

I have tried using SQL Server 2012's `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` against SQL Server 2008 Express.

- Geometries can be **`INSERT`** ed as long as they don't contain circular strings; if they do contain circular strings, which SQL Server 2008 does not support, this exception gets thrown:

  > ***`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`**: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 (`@geometry`): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type geometry. Check the source data for invalid values.*
- Geometries can be **`SELECT`** ed, but apparently only via Well-Known Text (WKT):

  ```cs
  // SELECT [Geometry].STAsText() FROM …
  var geometry = SqlGeometry.STGeomFromText(sqlDataReader.GetSqlChars(…), …);
  ```

  If one attempts to read the geometry directly:

  ```cs
  // SELECT [Geometry] FROM …
  var geometry = (SqlGeometry)sqlDataReader[…];
  ```

  then the following exception gets thrown (even if no circular strings are present in the geometries):

  > ***`System.InvalidCastException`**: [A]`Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry` cannot be cast to [B]`Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry`.*
  >
  > - *Type A originates from `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.`…*
  > - *Type B originates from `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.`…*

  (That exception is not thrown when `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` version 10 is used.)