# Could not load Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 10, but version 11 is referenced

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# application with multiple project referenced. One of the project is referencing Microsoft.SqlServer.Types (Version 11), because it is using SQLGeometry. When i install my application to an empty computer (Only windows 7 with VC++ 2010) i get an error in my application, that it "

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies.

Any ideas why it would require Version 10?

Answer (score 22):

[Please refer to this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18881556/70345) You need to do one of the following:

1. Add the `Type System Version=SQL Server 2012` keyword to your connection string in `app.config`:

`<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="YourConnectionStringName" connectionString="(connection string values);Type System Version=SQL Server 2012" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>`

2. Add a `bindingRedirect` for `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` in `app.config`:

`<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>`

Either option will ensure that `SqlConnection` will load version 11.0.0.0 of the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` assembly, instead of version 10.0.0.0.

Comment: There's also a chance that you don't have version 11 installed on your computer. In that case, you'll also have to download the 2012 SQL feature pack: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065

Comment: For later versions, use NuGet package `<package id="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" version="14.0.1016.290" targetFramework="net40-client" />` (and see ReadMe.htm installed as part of package to see actions required to load native assemblies at runtime). And the binding redirect `<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0-15.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>`

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your solution a project (csproj file) or the web/app.config is still referencing version 10.0.0.0. Search solution wide for the string 10.0.0.0 and you will find the reference.

Comment: Already tried that - found nothing. It seems that it tries to load assembly from GAC. Will try to set `SpecificVersion` to True.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, I was having this problem and traced the reference to a web.config file. I hadn't thought to look there since the class encountering the issue was part of a .dll file which had the correct reference (in a separate project).

I guess I've got something to learn still because I'm not sure why the website reference would apply for the classes being instantiated from the .dll.