# SqlServerTypes.Utilities is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, console-application, sqlgeography, .net-4.6.1

According to `SqlServerTypes` README I need to put this line:

`SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);`

before doing spatial operations for a desktop application (mine is a console app).

However it outputs an error on build:

`'Utilities' is inaccessible due to its protection level`

I went into the packages folder and found `Loader.cs` and the `Utilities` class is in fact internal? How would this have ever worked? I couldn't find anyone else with this problem and they are using it with no problems.

[image: Utilities]

If I F12 into the decompiled `Utilities` it is also marked as internal.

[image: SqlServerTypes]

I am using version `11.0.2`.

Comment: I have exactly the same. I used the nuget package `https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/` and have the same thing. Have you found a solution yet? Changing the internal to public did not fix it for me. Seems to keep crashing on the `Application_Start`.

Comment: @JPHellemons Well I did a hack around it. The problem with the package still exists. Since the DLL files are still copied to the output bin directory just not in the root director, I added a post-deployment script to copy the DLL script from the subdirectory to the root bin directory. Since there's no way of differentiating between 32 and 64-bit needs, you can only ever copy one or the other, which might not work for you. I know I will always use the 64-bit version.

Comment: I see things like this as proof-positive that nobody at Microsoft eats the dog-food when it comes to SqlClr or any of Sql Server's peripheral tools.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39589720/210916) has a workaround to using SqlServerTypes.Utilities, by changing assembly bindings in app.config (or web.config).

Answer (score 0):

Installing the nuget package to the MVC site as well as the domain layer fixed this issue for me. To begin with I only installed the package in the domain layer, where I actually use it.